# How to filter dynamodb in golang by global secondary index?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

I have a problem filtering the dynamodb table using Go.

The table has the following structure:

```
input := &dynamodb.CreateTableInput{
    BillingMode: aws.String("PAY_..."),

    AttributeDefinitions: []*dynamodb.AttributeDefinition{
        {
            AttributeName: aws.String("Id"),
            AttributeType: aws.String("N"),
        },
        {
            AttributeName: aws.String("Token"),
            AttributeType: aws.String("S"),
        },
    },
    KeySchema: []*dynamodb.KeySchemaElement{
        {
            AttributeName: aws.String("Id"),
            KeyType:       aws.String("HASH"),
        },
    },
    GlobalSecondaryIndexes: []*dynamodb.GlobalSecondaryIndex{
        {
            IndexName: aws.String("IdxGS"),
            KeySchema: []*dynamodb.KeySchemaElement{
                {
                    AttributeName: aws.String("Token"),
                    KeyType:       aws.String("HASH"),
                },
            },
            Projection: &dynamodb.Projection{
                ProjectionType: aws.String("ALL"),
            },
        },
    },
    TableName: aws.String("Entity"),
}
```

I tried different ways to filter it:

1st option:

```
queryInput := &dynamodb.QueryInput{
    TableName:              aws.String("Entity"),
    IndexName:              aws.String("IdxGS"),
    KeyConditionExpression: "Token = :token",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":token": token,
    },
    ProjectionExpression: "Id, Token"}

resp, err := DynamoDbClient.Query(queryInput)
```

And this piece of ...code is not compilable, don't have a clue why.

Also tried to use another type of the input request:
Option 2:

```
var queryInput = &dynamodb.QueryInput{
        TableName: aws.String("Entity"),
        IndexName: aws.String("IdxGS"),
        KeyConditions: map[string]*dynamodb.Condition{
            "TokenGS": {
                ComparisonOperator: aws.String("EQ"),
                AttributeValueList: []*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
                    {
                        S: aws.String(token),
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

And alghough it's compilable it does not pass the test.

I checked many different examples, either they do not work or they do not use GlobalSecondaryIndex.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to use https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/expression package which takes care of the proper setup of all `QueryInput` attributes.

Also for the example of usage, you check this repo https://github.com/zshamrock/dynocsv/blob/master/aws/dynamodb/dynamodb.go#L253.

So in your case this might look like this:

```
hash := expression.KeyEqual(expression.Key("Token"), expression.Value(token))
expr, _ := expression.NewBuilder().
    WithKeyCondition(hash).
    WithProjection(expression.NamesList(expression.Name("Id"), expression.Name("Token"))).
    Build()
queryInput := &dynamodb.QueryInput{
    TableName:              aws.String("Entity"),
    IndexName:              aws.String("IdxGS"),
    KeyConditionExpression: expr.KeyCondition(),
    ExpressionAttributeValues: expr.Values(),
    ProjectionExpression: expr.Projection()}
```